# Accessing TempData variables

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ajax to make a post request to my server side, I am creating a file, once that file has been created, I need to display it in my browser, I've read that using ajax is not possible to display that file, but I can use my `success` event in my ajax function to call another method in my server side, I've been trying to store that file as an array of bytes in memory using `TempData` or even `Session` variables, and then read them on the other method I'm calling on `ajax success`(called `DisplayFile`) , but the `TempData` variables are always null when the DisplayFile method is called... If you have different suggestions to do this are welcome,  I've been thinking in send the array of bytes to JQuery and then make another request passing it as a parameter but it is a very long array of bytes.., I'm not sure why the `TempData` value is null when `DisplayFile` method is called from client side...

```
$.ajax({ url: "/FileManagement/Files",
         type: 'post',
         data: formData,
         success: function(result){
           window.location = "/FileManagement/DisplayFile"
}
})

public JsonResult Files(//parameters...)
{
//...some code
 TempData["BytesArray"] = fileBytes; //fileBytes is an array of bytes
 TempData["FileName"] = fileName;  
}

public ActionResult DisplayFile()
{
var file = TempData["BytesArray"];  //null
var fileName = TempData["FileName"];
}
```

**UPDATE**
It's working now with Session variables instead of TempData, maybe it's because this controller is inside the Areas folder? This controller is not inside the Controllers folder, maybe it has to do with that, in order for Session to work I had to use the complete path to it like: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test"] = "asasa";` I'm still trying to figure out why with TempData the value is null when the second method is called...

Comment: If you are storing file somewhere the you return some identifier of file to Ajax response and another controller action should take that identifier as input and retrieve file content from the store and make it available for download.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I was using that approach but the file is being stored asynchronously and when I try to access it sometimes it has not been created yet, that's why I'm trying to retrieve the file as an array of bytes and then display it, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: I did exactly what you are trying to do. It worked for me. I have uploaded the project for your reference here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag2RGwevtqKWhmUkk_tRgJFIoMlA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up using `Session` variables, I'm using a controller inside `Areas` folder, so maybe because of that `TempData` isn't working the way I expect, for `Session` variables in order to work on this controller I have to use the complete path to it, while in a controller inside a `Controllers` folder I don't need to use that path..

```
public JsonResult Files(//parameters...)
{
//...some code
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["FileInBytes"] = bytesArray; //fileBytes is an array of bytes
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["FileName"] = fileName;;  
}

public ActionResult DisplayFile()
{
   var fileInBytes = Session["FileInBytes"] as byte[];
   var fileName = Session["FileName"] as string;
   Session.Remove("FileInBytes");
   Session.Remove("FileName"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you did was correct , you should be able to access the tempdata in the further get request ,even though it is from ajax.

See this accepted answer , which almost related to what you want

:https://forums.asp.net/t/1911620.aspx?How+to+pass+tempdata+to+controller+from+view+

casting may be a problem for you. try that.

Hope it will be helpful

Thanks
Karthik